# Not able to inspect Django migrations from test but working from Django command

Tags: django, django-migrations

I want to be able to inspect Django migrations within a test, so I can check basic sanity before running more expansive tests.

I was able to come up with the following in a Django command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db.migrations.loader import MigrationLoader


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Check migrations"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.migration_loader = MigrationLoader(None)
        self.migration_loader.build_graph()
        for root_node in self.migration_loader.graph.root_nodes():
            app_name = root_node[0]
            print(app_name, root_node[0])
```

But when I translate that into a test (using pytest):

```
from django.db.migrations.loader import MigrationLoader


def test_multiple_leaf_nodes_in_migration_graph():
        migration_loader = MigrationLoader(None)
        migration_loader.build_graph()
        for root_node in migration_loader.graph.root_nodes():
            app_name = root_node[0]
            print(app_name, root_node[0])
```

Then the graph (root nodes) returns an empty list.

The project is structured as follows:

```
django_project/
    settings.py
    ... # other Django core files
tests/
    test_above.py
django_app/
    models.py
    ... # other files from this app
    management/commands/
        command_above.py
pytest.ini
```

pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = django_project.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py
```

The command:

```
pytest --no-migrations
```

PS: the whole point of this is to be able to detect migration errors without running them.

Is there anything I need to do so I can "see" migrations within the test?

Comment: `--no-migrations` flag was the missing information to reproduce it. I've improved your question and added the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```sh
> pytest --no-migrations
> ```

Since you disabled migrations, the `MigrationLoader` won't load the migrations.

To load the migrations, you can override settings for `MIGRATION_MODULES`  just for that test:

```py
from django.test import override_settings


@override_settings(MIGRATION_MODULES={})  # Add this
def test_multiple_leaf_nodes_in_migration_graph():
    ...
```